# Defining variables and pointers in C++ (error: Segmentation fault (core dumped))

Tags: c++, pointers

I am learning assigning memory address by pointers is C++.

So to practice, I have written a code to show me a graph of a sinusoidal signal and the output of this signal when Hanning window is applied to it.
The outputs are written in text files and are then read by `gnuplot` to show the graphs. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int i;
 double y;
 int N=20;
 double Fs=30000;//sampling frequency
 double  T=1/Fs;//sample time 
 double f=5000;//frequency
 double *in;
 double t[N-1];//time vector 
 double *signal;

 for (int i=0; i< N;i++)
 {
    t[i]=i*T;
    signal[i] =0.7 *sin(2*M_PI*f*t[i]);// generate sine waveform
    double multiplier = 0.5 * (1 - cos(2*M_PI*i/(N-1)));//Hanning   Window
    in[i] = multiplier * signal[i];

   }

fstream myfile;

myfile.open("example2.txt",fstream::out);

myfile << "plot '-' using 1:2" << std::endl;
for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
 {
  myfile << i << " " << in[i] << std::endl;
  }

 myfile.close();

return 0;
}
```

So the error I am getting is: *Segmentation fault (core dumped)* and from what I read it has something to do with allocation of the memory. So my questions are:

1. When should we define the variables by pointers and assign memory
   address? Is it when we have an array of input and output? In this
   script can I simply write double in; or I have to write *in?
2. How can I get rid of this error: *Segmentation fault (core
   dumped)*

Comment: double *in (and similarly for the other variables) just creates the pointer, it does not assign memory. You have to assign memory to it before you can use it. Similar to when you have to declare the size of C style arrays when you declare the array itself.

Comment: @Suleman, so I always have to use a malloc function when I use a pointer?

Comment: Well since you're using C++, the better option is to just use a vector, or if you MUST have an array then declare an array double signal[N]; and then have a pointer to its first element int * signalPointer= &signal[0]; (Although it gets kind of pointless because you can directly do signal[i] =0.7 *sin(2*M_PI*f*t[i]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared:

```
double *in;
double *signal;
```

but there is no code to allocate memory for `in` or `signal`.

You can resolve the problem by making them arrays of size `N` at compile time,

```
double in[N];
double signal[N];
```

or by using `std::vector`

```
std::vector<double> in(N);
std::vector<double> signal(N);
```

or by allocating memory for them from the heap

```
double *in = new int[N];
double *signal = new int[N];
```

If you use the last approach, make sure to deallocate memory before the end of the function.

```
delete [] signal;
delete [] in;
```

Comment: can I just go with double signal and don't allocate any memory to it?

Comment: Then it will only be able to hold a SINGLE value, not an array of values. You need to make it an array, (or better a vector as Barry and R Sahu mentioned above)

Answer (score 0):

You never allocated memory for `in` or `signal`:

```
double *in;
double *signal;
...
for (int i=0; i< N;i++)
{
    signal[i] = ...
    in[i] = ...
}
```

As such, this is undefined behavior. You'd need to preface this with something like `double* in = new double[N]` or, even better, `std::vector<double> in(N)`.

Comment: so you need a pointer to the assigned memory which should be defined.  So std::vector<double> in(N) means I am assigning a memory for my in variable?

Comment: @MaryE The pointer has to point to something. [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a standard container that takes care of a lot of this stuff for you.

Comment: @MaryE Let's put it this way -- the vector class does all of the work that you were trying to do, only correctly.  The pointer used by vector is hidden within the vector class, so there is no need to be concerned about it.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation fault means that you are accessing memory that you haven't allocated.

In addition to the above answers:
You declare t

```
double t[N-1];//time vector
```

and then access it:

```
for (int i=0; i< N;i++) 
{
t[i]=i*T;
```

so you access beyond the bounds of the array on the last iteration of the for loop.  You should declare double t[N], or change your for loop boundaries.